# Convert uri to string with firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I get a simple example rom firebase how to [upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data) image to storage. Upload fine, and when `onSucess` i have uri to download something like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sexstartup-e3a65.appspot.com/o/User%3A%20epAPhTPZtUQwNprZpUIKOOc4DJk2%2Fimg.jpg?alt=media&token=49a479c2-fdfa-42ec-9376-278fca3b73e3
```

When i try to convert this uri to string i have `Nullpointerexception`, wat's wrong?

```
 Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
 String string_dwload = downloadUrl.toString();//valueOf not work too
```

Comment: Can you verify that `downloadUrl` is not `NULL`? That would explain the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla, i debbug app and `downloadUrl` = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....`

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i can screenshot my display is you wanna werificate it's

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code by calling  method `getDownloadUrl()` on the `taskSnapshot` object (instead of `getMetadata()`) - so your code in the `onSuccess` callback should look like this:

```
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        //get the download URL like this:
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        //and you can convert it to string like this:
        String string_dwload = downloadUrl.toString();        
    }
```

I hope this helps. By the way, please check the article/tutorial on [Uploading file on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)